# Project template for SharePoint 2016 is missing

Tags: development, 2016, visual-studio-2015

I have installed Visual Studio 15 (Enterprise) in my SharePoint 2016 RTM environment. Thereafter, I have installed [Office Developer Tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx). Unfortunately, SharePoint 2016 template is missing.

[image]

Comment: For the new coming visitors, check how you can install office developer tools for [**Visual Studio 2017**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/) & [**Visual Studio 2015**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/) & [**Visual Studio Community 2013**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the issue after installing

[Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683)