# Visual studio 2015 Visual Webpart sandboxed

Tags: web-part, sandbox-solution, visual-studio-2015

I want to create a visual webpart sandbox solution, I found this tool: "
Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint Power Tools" 
who don't  work with Visual studio 2015.
Do you have an idea, which tool should I use?
Thanks

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you targeting?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Office Developer tools outlined here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx

The visual webpart is found in the Office/SharePoint -> SharePoint Solutions category

[image]

You then need to set the project to `Sandboxed` in the project properties

Comment: thankx @Robert, I ll try it but did it have sandbox webpart in it or should I make something ?

Comment: from the add-in SharePoint I can't find new "webpart", no ascx or ascx.cs files

Comment: The tool you mentioned it works with VS community edition, I guess. For enterprise you will need https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683. I had this problem http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184606/project-template-for-sharepoint-2016-is-missing

Comment: If that link goes to Community edition, Microsoft has some errors in their linking. You need to have a higher version of Visual Studio than Community to develop SharePoint

Comment: @AtishDipongkor your related question is also for 2016 development, we are talking 2010 here ( I guess)

Comment: ohh.. I misunderstood.